# How to reference other module resource id in espresso test code in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, testing, module, android-espresso, multi-module

I am not able to access resource id from another module inside espresso test. I am trying to access 'history' resource identifier from one module to another module. But it says 'Can not resolve symbol'.[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default your `gradle.properties` will have

```
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

This means that you can no longer access library resources from your main app's `R` class. You will now have to import the libraries `R` class separately:

```
import com.example.app.R
import com.example.library.R as RLib 

// Now access your library resources like this: RLib.string.history
```

Alternatively switch `android.nonTransitiveRClass` to `false`.

This might be your issue.

Comment: I tried whatever you suggested. Still same issue.